# Using `Some` in a `let` statement in Rust

Tags: rust

In the following code (not mine):

```rust
    let store = Inventory {
        shirts: vec![ShirtColor::Blue, ShirtColor::Red, ShirtColor::Blue],
    };

    let user_pref1 = Some(ShirtColor::Red);
```

What is the purpose of the `Some` in the last line?

Comment: As others have pointed out, the "purpose" is to create a value of type `Option<ShirtColor>`. There isn't enough context here to explain *why* `user_pref1` needs to have that type instead of `ShirtColor`.

Comment: So, if it was mutable I would think this `Some()` would enable the var `user_pref1` to be reset to `None` later.  But it ain't mutable.  SO, perhaps the function does return a `Option`.  THANKS EVERYONE!

Answer (score 1):

`user_pref1` is type `Option<ShiftColor>`. `Some` is really `Option::Some`, the variant of [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html) that holds a value (unlike `None` which is similar to `null` or `nil`, the absence of a value).

[Explanation from the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html?highlight=option#the-option-enum-and-its-advantages-over-null-values)

> Rust does not have nulls, but it does have an enum that can encode the concept of a value being present or absent. This enum is `Option<T>` ...
>
> The `Option<T>` enum is so useful that it’s even included in the prelude; you don’t need to bring it into scope explicitly. Its variants are also included in the prelude: you can use Some and None directly without the `Option::` prefix. The `Option<T>` enum is still just a regular enum, and `Some(T)` and `None` are still variants of type `Option<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that `user_pref1` is an `Option<ShirtColor>`. Maybe the function returns options?